# How to create a bitmap cropping control in WinJS

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I want to create controls that lets the user decide crop area of a bitmap, in the common way, having four corners on the image. I saw that there is a sample C# app in the Microsoft site for this - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=bef08d57-fa4d-4d9c-9080-6ee55b8623c0

But I cannot figure out how to do this strictly WinJS. Do I need to create custom controls - if so how? Any sample code will help a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example in my [codeSHOW](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/codeshow/afc95986-7be9-4088-820d-4a20d1925c0d) project. It's the demo called Rx Crop. It uses Reactive Extensions (which are awesome by the way), but if you didn't want that dependency you could probably just use the example to figure out how to do it without.

BTW, the codeSHOW project has a bug and a usability issue currently. I have an update in certification. For now, just make sure you select the Rx Crop demo on the home screen and then click See the Code. If you hit See the Code with no demo selected it will crash.

Do me a favor and rate the app. Thanks.